# C++ hash function, how is the original haser i.e. hash<int xkey> implemented

Tags: c++, hash, hashset

I am new to the hashing in general and also to the STL world and saw the new [std::unrdered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) and the SGI :hash_set,both of which uses the [hasher hash](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html). I understand to get a good load factor , you might need to write your own hashfunction, and I have been able to write one.

However, I am trying to go deep into , how the original default has_functions are written. 
My question is :
1) How is the original default HashFcn written ; more concretely how is the hash generated?
Is it based on some pseudo random number. Can anyone point me to some header file (I am a bit lost with the documentation), where I can look up ; how the hasher hash is implemented.

2)How does it guarantee that each time , you will be able to get the same key?

Please, let me know if I can make my questions clearer any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version of gcc that I happen to have installed here, the required hash functions are in `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/functional_hash.h`

The hashers for integer types are defined using the macro `_Cxx_hashtable_define_trivial_hash`. As you might expect from the name, this just casts the input value to `size_t`.

This is how gcc does it. If you're using gcc then you should have a similarly-named file somewhere. If you're using a different compiler then the source will be somewhere else. It is not required that every implementation uses a trivial hash for integer types, but I suspect that it is very common.

It's not based on a random number generator, and hopefully it's now pretty obvious to you how this function guarantees to return the same key for the same input every time! The reason for using a trivial hash is that it's as fast as it gets. If it gives a bad distribution for your data (because your values tend to collide modulo the number of buckets) then you can either use a different, slower hash function or a different number of buckets (`std::unordered_set` doesn't let you specify the exact number of buckets, but it does let you set a minimum). Since library implementers don't know anything about your data, I think they will tend not to introduce slower hash functions as the default.

Answer (score 0):

A hash function must be deterministic -- i.e., the same input must always produce the same result.

Generally speaking, you *want* the hash function to produce all outputs with about equal probability for arbitrary inputs (but while desirable, this is no mandatory -- and for any given hash function, there will always be an arbitrary number of inputs that produce identical outputs).

Generally speaking, you want the hashing function to be fast, and to depend (to at least some degree) on the entirety of the input.

A fairly frequently seen pattern is: start with some semi-random input. Combine one byte of input with the current value. Do something that will move the bits around (multiplication, rotation, etc.) Repeat for all bytes of the input.